# REST Call not getting made using Jquery ajax feature

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an ajax call to a REST service. However I am not able to make the call.

below are my code snippet. I am not getting the alert that says 'ajax call initiated' or 'response from ajax call'. basically the control is not going inside the ajax method call. Please help. I am trying to integrate jquery with REST in my application.

### Index. html

added a check to see of DOM is loaded and I could able to see the alerts however the ajax call was not made successfully. any clue??

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var input = $('#userName').val();
    alert('user input: ' + input);
    var baseUrl = "http://localhost:8082/RestFulWeb/rest/userInfo/getUser/";
    var newUrl = baseUrl + input;
    alert('Url framed: ' + newUrl);
    alert('ajax call initiated');

   ( $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: newUrl,
        asynch: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Response from ajax call' + data);
            $('#outPut').html(data);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequestObj, Exception) {
            if (XMLHttpRequestObj.status == 0 || XMLHttpRequestObj.status == '') {
                alert('unknown error happened');

            } else if (XMLHttpRequestObj.status == 404) {
                alert('requested page not found');
            }
        }
    }));
   alert('ajax call ended');
});
});

</script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1>Welcome to rest service</H1>
<input id="userName" type="text" >
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" ">
<div id="outPut"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

### REST service:

```
package com.rest.webService;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

@Path(value = "/userInfo")
public class UserInfo {
    @GET
    @Path(value="/getUser/{userName}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String userName(@PathParam("userName")String userName){
        System.out.println("rest method called");
        return userName;
    }

}
```

got the alert 'ajax call initiated' and 'ajax call ended', however no alert saying 'response from ajax call'. kindly help

Answer (score 1):

`newUrl` is a string in your ajax call it should be the variable.

Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: newUrl,
```

Comment: I tried changing the newUrl still I am not able to invoke the method. even I am cannt see any alert

Comment: type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: newUrl,
        asynch: true,

Comment: async is without an `h` :) Have you tried invoking the route with the browser?